# Error "Property 'REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."?

Tags: typescript, redux

Ao configurar Redux DevTools obtenho o seguinte erro do TypeScript:

> Property '**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE**' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.

store.ts

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, Store } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { DevsState } from './ducks/devs/types';
import rootReducer from './ducks/rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './ducks/rootSaga';


export interface ApplicationState {
  devs: DevsState
}
const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
      // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
    }) : compose;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
);

const store: Store<ApplicationState> = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);


sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

Comment: Ao invés de `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` tente `window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__']`. Suspeito de uma situação (que ocorre no pré-parse do ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro, como eu [comentei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/432320/a-propriedade-redux-devtools-extension-compose-n%C3%A3o-existe-no-tipo-janela/433207?noredirect=1#comment837122_432320), é um problema do compilador/transpilador (chame como desejar) que é executado "fora" do navegador, a todo momento que o transpilador do TypeScript nota uma atualização em seus *sources* ele vai gerar novamente os scripts `.js`, nisto o objeto `window` não existe, pois o processo não ocorre no navegador, então como o objeto não existe vai emitir o erro:

> does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis

O **transpilador** de `TypeScript` **não necessariamente** é obrigado a entender que você vai executar seus scripts em um navegador ou em outro ambiente, porque a linguagem não tem foco de ambiente.

Sabendo disto o `window` vai ser processado para buscar o `REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE` no tempo desta transpilação, e como o objeto não existia até então, ele processa com um "possível" erro e para deste ponto.

A solução é fazer o seguinte *cast*: `window as any`, isto em TypeScript está forçando um `cast` da variável para `any`, e `any` pode ser "qualquer coisa", então assim o "transpilador" **não** vai esperar um objeto do tipo `Window` (usado em navegadores) ou do tipo `thisGlobal` (usado em Nodejs), como o `cast` disse que pode ser qualquer coisa então ele "compila" normalmente e no momento de executar o código no navegador ele vai funcionar normalmente.

Você pode fazer (como na sua própria resposta):

```
const composeEnhancers =
   typeof window === 'object' &&
   (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
   (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
}) : compose;
```

Ou então pode simplesmente reaproveitar em uma variável, algo como:

```
let win: any = window as any;

const composeEnhancers =
   typeof window === 'object' &&
   win.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
   win.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
}) : compose;
```

E assim poderia até reaproveitar a variável `win` em mais lugares de seu script, evitando os repetidos `cast`s

Vale notar que isto ocorre em outros ambientes, como Angular e Ionic, mas isto é porque eles também usam `TypeScript` e o problema tem a mesma origem.

Answer (score 1):

Minha solucao para o problema foi :

```
  const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
  (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
  }) : compose;
```

Comment: E poderia explicar o porque ela resolve e o porque este problema ocorre? Para que a pergunta e resposta sejam úteis para futuros visitantes

Comment: coloca ai mano para eu atualizar

Comment: Coloco como resposta, ok? A não ser que você saiba o motivo da necessidade disto e já queira editar a sua.

Comment: pode colocar a sua resposta

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso esto usando React com typeScript, o que resolveu foi:

Importe o pacote redux-devtools-extension no seu arquivo e use a função composeWithDevTools para criar o aprimorador da sua store. Em seguida, você pode passar o aprimorador como argumento para a função createStore. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(/* your middlewares here */))
);

export default store;
```